# Firebase Cloud Functions push Data to Array on User create

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const FieldValue = require('@google-cloud/firestore')
admin.initializeApp();


exports.collectEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const email = user.email;
    admin.firestore().collection('all_emails').doc('emails').update({
        email: FieldValue.arrayUnion(email)
  }) 
})
```

I still get the error: FieldValue.arrayUnion is not a function

Answer (score 4):

You're using an identifier `firebase` without defining it first.  That's not valid.

It looks like you copied code from the Firestore JavaScript SDK and pasted it into a place where you're using the Fireabse Admin SDK to work with Firestore.  These are different SDKs.  You should only use the Admin SDK on server side code, including Cloud Functions.

If you want to use [FieldValue from the admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.FieldPath), you'll need to refer to it from the admin SDK that you imported:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue
```

Unfortunately, this won't work (yet) because the admin SDK doesn't yet use the version of the Firestore node SDK that supports arrayUnion, which is 0.16.x.

So what you'll need to do is force an upgrade to the latest `@google-cloud/firestore` package (which the Admin SDK wraps)

```
npm install @google-cloud/firestore@latest
```

Then import it in your code:

```
import { FieldValue } from '@google-cloud/firestore'
```

Then use the newly imported version in your code:

```
email: FieldValue.arrayUnion(email)
```

Comment: Doug, what about the following mention in the latest Admin Node.js SDK Release Notes? "Upgraded the Cloud Firestore client from 0.15.4 to 0.16.0. This version contains a new array-contains query operator and FieldValue.arrayUnion() and FieldValue.arrayRemove() APIs."?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I done everything you said but when i do this import { FieldValue } from '@google-cloud/firestore' it is craching at the firebase functions deploy

Comment: Well, it's unfortunate that the API docs from the admin SDK that I linked to don't show the array operations yet.

Comment: If you have a crash, you're going to have to be more specific.  Did you install the module with npm as mentioned?

Comment: Yes and this is the Error: import { FieldValue } from '@google-cloud/firestore'

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import (and some arrows pointing at the import)

Comment: I'm using typescript.  You'll have to convert to javascript and use require() instead.

Comment: still the error "FieldValue.arrayUnion is not a function" i edited my Question above so that you can see my full code now.

Comment: When you use require, you're getting the entire Firestore SDK, not just FieldValue.  You'll need to get a hold of FieldValue directly from the thing you import.  Typically you import to something called `firestore`, then say `firestore.FieldValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check in your `package.json` file that you have the latest version of "firebase-admin", i.e. version 6.0.0 (at the time of writing this answer).

See the Admin Node.js SDK Release Notes [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node), which indicate that, with this version, there was an upgrade to the Cloud Firestore client which contains the `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` and `FieldValue.arrayRemove()` APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i get still the error "Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined"

Comment: And what happens if you do `email: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(email)`?

Comment: Same Error... :(

Comment: Actually this doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) says that for Node.js it is not supported yet... Not sure which doc we should consider...

Comment: See my answer for the right way to do this until the admin sdk is updated.